# Picking an element within a DIV with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an HTML page with a variety of divs on it. For instance, something like this:

```
<div id="myDiv1">
  <input id="myInput1" type="text" />
  <input id="myInput2" type="text" />
  <input id="myButton" type="button" value="Button" />
</div>

<div id="myDiv2">
  <!-- My Content -->
</div>
```

How do I use JQuery to:

1. Get ALL input fields of type text within myDiv1
2. Get a single input field inside of a div

Traditionally, I would use the following:

```
var textFields = $(":text");
var myInput = $("#myInput1");
```

However, I would really like to understand how to search within a single DIV element.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) method.

```
$('#myDiv1').find('input[type="text"]');
$('#myDiv1').find('input#myInput1');
```

If you know that the inputs are direct [children](http://api.jquery.com/children/) of #myDiv1 (this is faster)

```
$('#myDiv1').children('input[type="text"]');
```

Or you can also use an optional second parameter to $, which is the [context](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context).

```
$('input[type="text"]', '#myDIv1');
```

You should also store #myDiv1 since you are using it more than one time:

```
var $myDIv  = $('#myDiv1'),
    $inputs = $myDiv.children('input[type="text"]'),
    $input  = $myDiv.children('input#myInput1');
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an optional context parameter for jquery selectors which does exactly what do you want to do;

```
var a = $("a", "#yourDiv");
var p = $("input[type='text']", $("#myDiv"));
```

Context parameter either could be a string or jquery object.